# Checking if exist if not add

Tags: java

```java
public void land(Plane plane) {
  Plane idC =(Plane) plane;
  if(!Planes.contain(idC.getId())) {
    id=id+1;
    idC.setId(id);
    Planes.add(idC);
  }
}
```

Plane has a structure with some strings and serials and it contains an id Plane(string,string,int,int). i am trying to find if my arraylist Planes contains the id of a plane already. if it does do nothing. if it does not, add the plane, while also giving it a new id. however, i seem to have some sort of trouble doing this. where am i going wrong?

Comment: _some sort of trouble_ Can you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: let us know what is going wrong first.

Comment: You java code is pretty wrong in many ways. And we need more informations. For example, what is `Planes` ? An `ArrayList<Integer>` or and `ArrayList<Plane>` ?

Comment: Why are you casting a `Plane` type to a `Plane` type?  Unless those are different packages, that isn't necessary.

Comment: in the test there is preset a single plane to the value 2 then 4 other planes is added to the arraylist with meaning they gain the id's 1,2,3,4 the plane with preset is then added however my code should make sure that that fifth plane with the preset value is ignored, however it doesnt?

Comment: Are you sure the incoming "plane" has an id?  It appears you're checking the existence of the plane before assigning the id.

Comment: the planes arraylist is made so that it contains all the values Plane (ArrayList<Plane> Planes =new ArrayList<Plane>)
and im trying to find the id of said plane to see if my airport aldready contains a matching id, if it does the plane should not be added with a new id

Answer (score 0):

If Planes is an array list of Plane, then simply pass Plane as an object to check if it is contained in the array list....
You may need to declare your array list like this: `ArrayList<Plane> Planes = ..`

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not quite sure about your logic behind this, I'm assuming you want something like this:

```
public class Planes {
    private Map<String, Plane> planes;

    public Planes() {
        this.planes = new HashMap<String, Plane>();
    }

    public boolean contains(Plane plane) {
        return this.planes.contains(plane.getId());
    }

    public void add(Plane plane) {
        this.planes.put(plane.getId(), plane);
    }
}

public class SomePlaneRelatedClass {
    private Planes planes;

    public SomePlaneRelatedClass() {
        this.planes = new Planes();
        ...
    }

    ...

    public void land(Plane plane) {
        if (!this.planes.contains(plane)) {
            plane.setId(/* some generated ID */);
            this.planes.add(plane);
        }
    }
}
}
```

One comment, though. If you're gonna if your collection contains the plane, don't use a list.

Imagine a scenario when you have a lot of planes, and you're querying for the last one. It's gonna iterate over the whole list to find it (time complexity is `O(n)`). Rather use Maps that will map your UUID to your Plane and get it by UUID, which should be quite faster (`O(1)`).